# Is there a way to send data over computers other than UDP and Bluetooth?

Tags: c#, bluetooth, udp

I want to make a simple desktop app that receives data from my phone and does certain stuff accordingly. I don't need to send any more than 1 byte. I tried UDP but it requires firewall bypassing which is a spooky popup to click on. I also tried Bluetooth but I couldn't get it to work because most of the documentation is about BLE not Bluetooth Classic. Is there any other way I can communicate with another device from a short distance even if I'm just limited to sending 1 byte? I would like topics to research but code samples are also welcome, preferably in C#.

Comment: Outgoing connections usually don't prompt for the firewall, so just have 2 clients send to a server or a database on a web server.

Comment: What's wrong with Bluetooth Low Energy?

Comment: For one byte, use a TCP connection on port 80.  That will always be open on the firewall.